# Test if two binary trees are equal

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, tree

I know this may be a duplicate post, but I would submit my own code to your attention.
I wrote the following recursive procedure, but I would like to optimize it.
I would like to stop the treeCompare method as soon as I find a node different from other, instead of comparing all nodes.

Thanks in advance for your help.

This is my thin Node class:

```
public class Node {
    public Node father;
    public Node left;
    public Node right;
}
```

And this is my comparator method:

```
private boolean treeCompare(Node firstNode, Node secondNode) {
    if (firstNode == null && secondNode == null)
        return true;
    else if (firstNode == null || secondNode == null)
        return false;

    boolean isLEquals = treeCompare(firstNode.left, secondNode.left);
    boolean isREquals = treeCompare(firstNode.right, secondNode.right);

    return firstNode.equals(secondNode) && isLEquals && isREquals;
}
```

Comment: Almost each binary tree has its isomorphic equivalents, do you need to check it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
private boolean treeCompare(Node firstNode, Node secondNode) {
    if (firstNode == secondNode)
        return true;

    if (firstNode == null || !firstNode.equals(secondNode))
        return false;

    return treeCompare(firstNode.left, secondNode.left) && treeCompare(firstNode.right, secondNode.right);
}
```

Comment: Tail Recursion is the solution

Comment: Now if you start comparing two roots node, and these are equal, the method returns immediately true and stops. This prevent a node per node in depth comparison, isn't it? In my opinion the previous version is better.

Comment: firstNode == secondNode returns true if both instances are null or the same. If they are the same, they have the same left and right nodes, so no other operation is needed. Correct me if I'm wrong :)

Comment: @andrucz, you are right. I misunderstood the use of the `==` operator, instead of the equals method. `==` return true if the instances are right the same!

Comment: That's a common mistake. I'm glad I was able to help.

Comment: @JohnMòf could you please mark this answer as correct, if it helped?